# Date Range Between Start Date and End Date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sticking with data do you know the formula for the below question.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOhbU.png)

The result should be 1 if the date is between the start date and the end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### IF Statement And Locking References

In cell `E2` use:

```
=IF(AND(E$1>=$A2,E$1<=$B2),1,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try in this way as well, `BOOLEAN LOGIC`

Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=(E$1>=$A2)*(E$1<=$B2)
```

**And Fill Down & Fill Across**

And set the formatting as --> Select the ranges, press **CTRL 1** --> **Format Cells** --> **Number Tab** --> **Custom** --> **Type** --> **0;;**

Note On **BOOLEAN LOGIC** :

• A `Boolean` is a data type with only two possible values, `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

• `Boolean` values is that they have numeric equivalents that can be used in formulas.

• During a math operation, Excel will coerce **Booleans into numbers**, `TRUE` becomes **"1"**, and `FALSE` becomes **"0"**.

• **No Nesting**. **No IF statements**. Excel simply runs the calculation and returns the result. That's the gist of **Boolean logic**.

[image: BOOLEAN_LOGIC]

Comment: Have you seen that the custom format also works for `;0`. It will add a trailing semicolon though (`;0;`).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, never tried that way, but my regional settings works for this `0;;` . I shall try the one you have mentioned, and let you know!

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, I tried using as you mentioned `;0` but it hides everything, and I saw it automatically created `;0;` and showing nothing